# Issue while running offline compaction in AEM 6.1 SP2 CFP3

Tags: aem

I am running offline compaction to reduce aem repository size. but it is throwing error [*05:28:37.939 [main] ERROR o.a.j.o.p.segment.SegmentTracker - Segment not found:
3ff5d2ae-2b7f-412b-bfff-1dcdf0613315. Creation date delta is 15 ms.
org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.plugins.segment.SegmentNotFoundException: Segment 3ff5
d2ae-2b7f-412b-bfff-1dcdf0613315 not found*].

Compaction was working fine earlier, when we were using AEM 6.1 only with communities FP4 and have oak version 1.2.7. 
Problem occurred after installation of communities FP5, FP6, service pack 2 and CFP3 in AEM 6.1, now oak version upgraded to 1.2.18 and we are using oak jar version 1.2.18 to perform the compaction. 
When I Google this error then found that our segments have been corrupted and we have to restore our segment with last good condition.
Then we have found a command this [*java -jar D:\aem\oakfile\oak-run-1.2.18.jar check -d1 --bin=-1 -p D:\aem\crx-quickstart\repository\segmentstore*] to find the last good condition segment where we can restore. But when we are running this command to find the previous good segment then this command is keep running to infinite without end.

Can anyone let me know how I can fix this?